# hstore error restoring postgres using pg_restore. How to fix?

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I have a postgres database on a ubuntu server. The output of `psql --version` is
`psql (PostgreSQL) 10.15 (Ubuntu 10.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)`. I create a dump of this database using the command

```
pg_dump -U curiouslearn -h localhost -p 5432 -Fc -f mydb.dump mydb
```

Then I copy the file to my local machine (which is running Mac OSX) and has the postgres version
`psql (PostgreSQL) 13.2`.

I try to restore the database to a different name using the following sequence of commands.

1. I create the db using `createdb mydbtest`.
2. Then, I connect to the database using `psql -d mydbtest`.
3. I run `DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS PUBLIC;` (If I don't do this, I get an error saying the schema public already exists).
4. I run the command:
   `pg_restore --no-owner --no-privileges -d mydbtest mydb.dump`

My problem is that I get the errors below. Can you please suggest how to fix them? Thank you. I searched a lot but there are not many results with `"$libdir/hstore"`. There was nothing that was helpful. If you can think of some things I can try. Thank you.

```
pg_restore: from TOC entry 2; 3079 18199 EXTENSION hstore
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/hstore": No such file or directory
Command was: CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore WITH SCHEMA public;


pg_restore: from TOC entry 3061; 0 0 COMMENT EXTENSION hstore
pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR:  extension "hstore" does not exist
Command was: COMMENT ON EXTENSION hstore IS 'data type for storing sets of (key, value) pairs';
```

Comment: Assuming you are installing using an APT repo you need to install the `postgresql-contrib-10`(or something close to that) package in order to have the `hstore` extension libraries present.

Comment: Thank you @AdrianKlaver. Install it on my Mac where I am getting the error? The funny thing is I have hstore on Mac. But maybe that is for version 13 and I need to install for version 10. Is that the reason? Or, maybe its location is different on Mac. Thank you.

Comment: If you open `psql` and as superuser `CREATE EXTENSION hstore;` does it work? FYI, you don't need to worry about the `PUBLIC` schema error, it just a notice and the restore will continue on.

Comment: Hello @AdrianKlaver. Running `CREATE EXTENSION hstore` gives `ERROR:  extension "hstore" already exists` because it already exists for another database. But for the database that I am trying to create, `mydbtest` I get the error `ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/hstore": No such file or directory`.

Comment: Do this in a new database eg. `CREATE DATABASE new_db;`, connect to it and then `CREATE EXENSION hstore;`

Comment: Thank you for your help @AdrianKlaver. Before I read your last comment, I restarted my computer and tried again. That fixed the issue. I don't what went wrong earlier. Sorry for taking your time.